# old multiselect array using select option in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

am trying to make old values which would be used when am editing but it's returning
`htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given`everytime
but when i dd the variable i found that it has array but when it reaches the option it changes into error

this is my select in blade

```
        {!! Form::label('functional_area_id', 'Functional Area', ['class' => 'bold']) !!} 
        <?php
       $functionalAreaIds = old('functional_area_id',$jobFunctionalAreasIds);
        ?>                   
        {{-- this codes works perfect but it doesn't display the relation between child and parent and i want that to be displayed
{!! Form::select('functional_area_id[]', $functionalAreas, $functionalAreaIds, array('class'=>'form-control select2-multiple', 'id'=>'functional_area_id','multiple'=>'multiple')) !!} --}}
        <select name="functional_area_id[]" id="functional_area_id" class="form-control select2-multiple" multiple="multiple">
            @foreach ($menulist as $category)
                <option value={{ $category->functional_area_id }} {{ $functionalAreaIds }} >{{ $category->functional_area }}</option>

                @if (count($category->children) > 0)
                    @include('submenu', ['submenu' => $category->children, 'parent' =>
                    $category->functional_area])
                @endif

            @endforeach
        </select>

        {!! APFrmErrHelp::showErrors($errors, 'functional_area_id') !!}                                       
    </div>
```

this is the controller which fetches the array

```
public function jobFunctionals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\JobFunctionalAreas', 'job_id', 'id');
}

public function getJobFunctionalsArray()
{
    return $this->jobFunctionals->pluck('functional_area_id')->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only output strings using `{{ $variable }}`, because Blade will run `$variable` through `htmlspecialchars` escaping, that's why you get an error trying to output `{{ $functionalAreaIds }}` which, judging by the name, is an array.

I have no idea what you are including with the `submenu` partial, but it is likely invalid HTML. The only tags that are allowed within a `select` element are `option` and `optgroup` tags. Optgroups need to be opened and closed around options, so I don't see how this would work in your setup.

Also, you have syntax errors in your `option` tag:

```html
<option value={{ $category->functional_area_id }} {{ $functionalAreaIds }} >{{ $category->functional_area }}</option>
```

What do you expect this to do? This would - if it worked at all - result in something like this:

```html
<option value=1 [1,5,6] >Area 1</option>
```

Which is clearly not valid HTML. What do you expect the array to do after every option value?

To fix the `option` part of your code, you can do something like this:

```html
<option value="{{ $category->functional_area_id }}" @if(in_array(category->functional_area_id, $functionalAreaIds)) selected @endif >{{ $category->functional_area }}</option>
```

This will set all options selected that are within the `$functionalAreaIds` array.

Maybe you should get rid of the code including the `submenu` when testing, because this is likely to break your HTML too, and then take it from there.

Another tip:

```php
<?php
       $functionalAreaIds = old('functional_area_id',$jobFunctionalAreasIds);
?>
```

can be written in blade like this:

```php
@php($functionalAreaIds = old('functional_area_id',$jobFunctionalAreasIds))
```

Comment: for your information the submenu is included because i display relationship between parent and child on the select dropdown.
also when if you look the codes in the comment it's writen as that it works the ploblem with it is that the relationship doesn't be displayed and i have'nt figured a way to display it in the form:select so that's why.
thanks tho am goin to try the tip you gave about removing html.

Comment: So, did it work for you? :-)

Comment: no, still trying...

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: can't figure out how to display the old value which would come as a multiselect values